# Regex: only letters and required hyphens

Tags: regex

I need to build a regex that allows only letters and hyphens, but it needs to require the hyphens.

I tried:

- `^[a-z]+[a-z\-]+[a-z]+$` (the match without hyphens pass)
- `([A-Za-z\-]+)` (the match without hyphens pass too)
- `[a-zA-Z][\-]+` (it didn't work)

Could someone write it to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to know more... Like *where* is a hyphen required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a look ahead:

```
^(?=.*-)[a-zA-Z-]+$
```

That little expression `(?=.*-)` is a "look ahead", which is a non-consuming assertion that `.*-` appears somewhere ahead, which means "there needs to be hyphen in the input"

Also, when put first or last the hyphen is a *literal* hyphen that doesn't need escaping, otherwise a hyphen denotes a range.

Comment: @GustavoGondim No problem! It's good to learn about "look arounds" - they are really useful and powerful.

Comment: Just for curiosity, I am using it on a MVC route constraint. Now my app knows the difference between the action "create" and the profile alias "my-profile-name"! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the other answers *require* a hyphen. Try `[a-zA-Z-]*[-][a-zA-Z-]*`

Comment: My answer *does* require a hyphen - check it out. Also, compare my answer with yours - you might see a more versatile way to assert conditions about the input

Comment: *more versaile*? I don't know about that. *Slower*, yeah. But *more versatile*, I don't know.

Comment: Lookaheads are certainly more versatile. Maybe less efficient, but that's the trade-off for more functionality. It also depends heavily on how two regex's are written and what the content you're matching is at to whether one is slower than the other. In fact, the regex as written above could be significantly slower if processed by an NFA engine, assuming there were multiple hyphens in the string, due to the number of backtracks that would be processed. Of course, there's then the issues with DFA's not being able to do lookarounds to counteract that argument, but slow/versatile is a big topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question lists all of the requirements. Going off of all that you said, this pattern will allow letters and hyphens and at least 1 hyphen is required.

```
[a-zA-Z-]*-[a-zA-Z-]*
```

This allows the string "-" is that OK?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say which language, so here is Javascript:

```
Code-> "te-st".match(/[A-Za-z-]+/)
Result -> ["te-st"]
```

Comment: Sorry, but, as I said, I tried this expression before. It allows only letters.

Comment: AH, missed the required the hyphen bit.  Apologies.